# CPU requirement to run logistic regression with pairwise interactions

Tags: r, cpu, logistic-regression, pairwise

I am trying to fit a logistic regression model with pairwise interactions for 7 variables; however, I have let the code run for as long as 12 hours, and still no results. My dataset is not terribly large…about 3000 lines. One of my variables has 82 degrees of freedom, and I am wondering if that is the problem? I have no problem running the code with main level effects, but I expect interactions between my variables, so I would like pairwise interactions included. I have tried adding arguments to the code to speed up the process, but I still can’t get the code to kick back results even after 12 hours of running. I am using the glmulti package to fit the model, and I included the method = “g” argument and the conseq = 5 argument in an attempt to make the code run faster. Is there anything else I can do to speed it up? Another code or different package, or is a basic laptop just not enough to run it?

This is the code I used:

```
detectmodel<- glmulti::glmulti(outcome~ bird + year + season + sex + numobs + obsname + season + month, data=detect, level=2, fitfunction=glm, crit="aicc", family=binomial, confsetsize=10, method = "g")
```

[image: data set image]

Comment: Is the data maybe grouped? Are you inserting a column that is too big in terms of factor-levels, that might be causing this? I'd ask you to put up the data, and the code, to diagnose this better.

Comment: I added the code I used and a screenshot of my data...In my bird column, I have 82 different birds, each with at least 10 observations. Essentially, I have 82 factor levels for that column. I wanted to include that variable in the logistic regression...Do I need to remove it based on number of factor levels?

Comment: I'd have to explore this much closer before saying anything concrete.

Comment: You can try to use fewer covariates, and see if it works faster that way, and then incrementally add new ones until you find the culprit.

Comment: If it is the factor, then try to count how many occurrences of the factor that is present in the data (either using `dplyr::count`, or `{vtree}` or anything like that). \

Comment: Also, I don't see any `family = binomial` or anything, and that information is necessary somehow, otherwise I don't know what you're running.

Comment: In my head, year, and month are also factors and not numerics, but that's maybe subjective.

Comment: I'll try adding one by one and see what is causing the issue!

Comment: I would strongly suggest a mixed effect model with bird as a random effect.